# Dominant Resource Fairness in YARN

Tags: hadoop-yarn

I would like to implement Dominant Resource Fairness (DRF) or other scheduling algorithms in apache yarn. Does anybody know how to implement it? Is there any source?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can refer to [DominantResourceFairnessPolicy.java](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/server/resourcemanager/scheduler/fair/policies/DominantResourceFairnessPolicy.java) in the fair scheduler for more information.